# Accessing Select element value in angular2 gives Error

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using angular 2 rc4
My view is as following:

```html
<select class="form-control" (change)="selectTestName=this.value;getChartData()">
    <option *ngFor="let st of selectTestNameList" value="{{st.selectTestName}}">{{st.selectTestName}}</option>
</select>
```

After change it throws following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_GeneralTrnd0._handle_change_20_0 (GeneralTrnd.template.js:367)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:25), <anonymous>:316:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:45), <anonymous>:278:36)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:48), <anonymous>:20:93)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:17), <anonymous>:45:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:230)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:17), <anonymous>:78:78)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:13), <anonymous>:228:73)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<select class="form-control" #selectbox (change)="selectTestName=selectbox.value;getChartData()">
  <option *ngFor="let st of selectTestNameList" value="{{st.selectTestName}}">{{st.selectTestName}}</option>
</select>
```

You have to assign a name to the selectbox. You can use that name to access the value.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this.value` use `$event.target.value`.

```html
<select class="form-control" (change)="selectTestName=$event.target.value;getChartData()">
    <option *ngFor="let st of selectTestNameList" value="{{st.selectTestName}}">{{st.selectTestName}}</option>
</select>
```